# How can I extract images from a PDF file?

Tags: php, perl, pdf

I need to extract all the images from a PDF file on my server. I don't want the PDF pages, only the images at their original size and resolution.

How could I do this with Perl, PHP or any other UNIX based app (which I would invoke with the exec function from PHP)?

Comment: How do you know where each image is on the page?  To the best of my knowledge, PDF files do not record this information.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[pdfimages](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/pdfimages1.html) does just that. It's is part of the poppler-utils and xpdf-utils packages.

From the manpage:

> Pdfimages saves images from a Portable Document Format  (PDF)  file  as Portable Pixmap (PPM), Portable Bitmap (PBM), or JPEG files.
>
> Pdfimages  reads  the  PDF file, scans one or more pages, PDF-file, and writes one PPM, PBM, or JPEG file for each  image,  image-root-nnn.xxx, where  nnn  is  the image number and xxx is the image type (.ppm, .pbm, .jpg).
>
> NB: pdfimages extracts the raw image data from the  PDF  file,  without performing  any  additional  transforms.  Any rotation, clipping, color inversion, etc. done by the PDF content stream is ignored.

Comment: I think the package gets installed when you install xpdf.

Comment: that is correct too, both packages have pdfimages.

Answer (score 11):

With regards to Perl, have you checked [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org)?

- [PDF::GetImages](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=PDF-GetImages&mode=module) - get images from pdf document
- [PDF::OCR](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=PDF-OCR&mode=module) - get ocr and images out of a pdf file
- [PDF::OCR2](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=PDF-OCR2&mode=module) - extract all text and all image ocr from pdf

Answer (score 3):

pdfimages is nice as it does not reencode but only extract jpegs. But there is a bug:

pdfimages comes from package "poppler-utils" or from the bigger "xpdf-utils". At least in Ubuntu "poppler-utils" comes already pre-installed. The pdfimages in poppler-utils 10.0.3 (Ubuntu 9.04 Jaunty) still does not react to the option "-j" to extract ".jpg". It always extracts ".ppm".

As a workaround you may replace "poppler-utils" with "xpdf-utils":
$ sudo apt-get install xpdf-utils

with kind regards,

+++ Oliver

Comment: on my ubuntu server neither xpdf nor poppler recognizes the `-j` switch