# Photo extraction from pdf file

Tags: pdf, automation, adobe

Does anyone know of a way i can extract all jpg images from a pdf file? I am currently using Acrobat and i have a file that contains about 1500 photos that i need to extract but doing them one at a time would be much too time consuming. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate question, answered here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/430707/how-can-i-extract-images-from-a-pdf-file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/430707/how-can-i-extract-images-from-a-pdf-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just doing a little search i found this, i hope it helps... i cant think of any reason there'd be 1500 images in a pdf.

http://pdf-image-extraction-wizard.lastdownload.com/

Answer (score 1):

There are free utilities that can help you do this. For example, a quick Google search turned up [this one](http://somepdf.com/some-pdf-image-extract.html).

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac try the app [FileJuicer](https://echoone.com/filejuicer/) - this normally works really well at extracting images from PDFs

Answer (score 0):

Coding answer (requires tesseract (free software)). I'm not sure which of the packages I actually used for that bit of code, some packages are there for other functions in the same code block.

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import cv2
import os
import subprocess

#Strip images and put them in the relevant directory
def image_exporter(pdf_path, output_dir):
    if not os.path.exists(output_dir):
        os.makedirs(output_dir)

    cmd = ['pdfimages', '-all', pdf_path,
           '{}/prefix'.format(output_dir)]
    subprocess.call(cmd)
    print('Images extracted:')
    print(os.listdir(output_dir))
```