# How can I extract images from a PDF file?

Tags: perl, pdf, image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I extract images from a PDF file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430707/how-can-i-extract-images-from-a-pdf-file)

I am able to extract the images from a PDF file using many Perl modules, but none of them specifies the exact positions of the images being extracted (where the image actually belongs).

Could anyone suggest to me how to extract the images along with their positions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An indirect solution is to use `pdfimages` to scan the pdf file page by page. If there is an image, at least you will know which page it is in.

For example, you can use `pdfinfo` to find out the number of pages there are in a given pdf file, and use `pdfimages` with the `-f` and `-l` options to scan a particular page.