# convert:not authorized `aaaa` @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/453

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I want to create a captcha pic by use `convert` from ImageMagick.

And I follow [this](http://www.grant-trebbin.com/2014/02/generating-captcha-from-linux-command.html), but there are some problem .

Input In my linux shell:

```
convert -background white -fill black -font FreeSerif-Bold -pointsize 36 label:'adfgh' ./test.png
```

The Error is:

> convert:not authorized `adfgh` @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/453.
>   convert:missing an image filename `./test.png` @
>   error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3015

My ImageMagick: Version:6.7.2-7 , I install it with `yum install ImageMagick` .

I'm clueless. Any advice please?

Comment: Double check `policy.xml`. Security options may prevent `label:` protocol.

Comment: thanks! I modify the policy.xml, comment this line" <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="LAEBL"> ". It does work ! Thanks !

Comment: Where is the policy.xml ?

Comment: /etc/ImageMagick/policy.xml

Comment: Thank you everyone! It worked for me, as well. @jianwei, you should add an answer. Also, there's a minor typo in @jianwei's code - you should comment out this line: `<policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="LABEL" />`

Comment: /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml

Comment: For debugging purposes, you can also just rename or remove the policy.xml file to remove the security restrictions and see what effect that has on your problem. `identify -list policy` command shows the current policy.

Answer (score 485):

> **Note: the solution in this and other answers involves disabling safety measures that are there to fix arbitrary code execution vulnerabilities. See for instance [this ghostscript-related](https://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/332928/) and [this ubuntu-related](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/imagemagick/8:6.7.7.10-6ubuntu3.13) announcement. Only go forward with these solutions if the input to `convert` comes from a trusted source.**

I use ImageMagick in php (v.7.1) to slice PDF file to images.

First I got errors like:

> Exception type: ImagickException
>
> Exception message: not authorized ..... @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/412

After some changes in `/etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml` I start getting erroes like:

> Exception type: ImagickException
>
> Exception message: unable to create temporary file ..... Permission denied @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/465

**My fix**:

In file `/etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml` (or `/etc/ImageMagick/policy.xml`)

1. comment line

   ```xml
   <!-- <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="MVG" /> -->
   ```
2. change line

   ```xml
   <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PDF" />
   ```

   to

   ```xml
   <policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PDF" />
   ```
3. add line

   ```xml
   <policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="LABEL" />
   ```

Then **restart your web server** (nginx, apache).

Comment: This should be the acceptable answer if you experienced this problem on an Ubuntu box since Oct 4 2018. Any other issues from other distros?

Comment: I am also just getting this problem just today on Ubuntu 16.04. Did something change?

Also I didn't need to add the LABEL line, just change the rights for PDF from "none" to "read".

Comment: Solves a very similar problem in my Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS box

Comment: In my server, the `policy.xml` file last updated on Sept 29, but the problems just arise today. I'm using ubuntu server 14.04.5, but set auto update. In apt log, I found about this update: `imagemagick-common:amd64 (6.7.7.10-6ubuntu3.12, 6.7.7.10-6ubuntu3.13),`

Comment: here is the related changelog: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/imagemagick/8:6.7.7.10-6ubuntu3.13

Comment: Proven solution on Laravel Forge env, if your spatie pdf got into error "ImagickException: not authorized" then this is a solution

Comment: Dont't forget to restart php-fpm as well `sudo systemctl restart php7.2-fpm` or whatever version you have

Comment: It worked for me. But I've checked CVE-2016-3714 answer from @Nikolay Ivanov so I left the "MVG" comment out of my config and still it worked, since I'm using Imagick only for PDF conversion.

Comment: Can someone explain what domain="coder" relates to? I made the above changes and this gets the issue fixed when a user is loading an image for conversion. My site is running on Laravel forge and I am using a Redis queue to complete image conversions. With this setup then the only way to get it working is to comment out/remove the PDF/LABEL lines. I assume this is because this is then being run by a system level user. Can domain="??" be set to work for cron/system users?

Comment: My problem is that this policy file can only be edited by the superuser. Is there any way to control policy locally? Something like `~/.imagemagick/policy.xml`

Comment: For command line usage, e.g. `convert 1.png 2.png out.pdf`, the only change you need is `<policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PDF" />`.

Comment: On ubuntu 18.04 I only comment the lines under the line: `<!-- disable ghostscript format types -->` and work.

Comment: This fixed the issue for me in Linux Mint 18.3.

Comment: Don't do this. This restriction has been introduced as a security measure because of possible remote code execution (see https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/imagemagick/8:6.7.7.10-6ubuntu3.13). So the correct answer is: You should use another program for this task.

Comment: Make sure to update ghostscript https://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/332928/

Comment: You don't need to restart your webserver - ImageMagick is a separate service.

Comment: The most important thing is: Are the new safety measures introduced in the ImageMagick package permanent or is it just a hotfix and a proper solution that will both fix the security issue and not crash current third-party scripts is planned to be implemented later? I am asking because I installed the newest version of ImageMagick 7 and I *think* that my scripts no longer crash again without fixing anything in the policy file.

Comment: @Marian thanks for reminding the security issues. But what's the point of distributing a software that does not work? It is for the case when users will assume the security. Not everyone manage a server exposed to attacks. I run convert in a sandboxed VM behind a firewall, for converting eps to some word compatible format. That's one of the most difficult to maintain software chain. Every soft I tried so far did rot. I'm very happy to find those answer and I WILL do this, definitely!

Answer (score 179):

I use many times the ImageMagic `convert` command to convert `*.tif` files to `*.pdf` files.

I don't know why but today I began to receive the following error:

```
convert: not authorized `a.pdf' @ error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1028.
```

After issuing the command:

```
convert a.tif a.pdf
```

After reading the above answers I edited the file `/etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml`

and changed the line:

```
policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PDF"
```

to

```
policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PDF"
```

and now everything works fine.

I have "ImageMagick 6.8.9-9 Q16 x86_64 2018-09-28"
on "Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS".

Comment: I'm on openSuse Leap 15.0 and used "compare" to compare PDF pages, same error, _even_ after an update by openSuse on October 10th 2018. After changing the line as described here, it worked.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu Xenial 16.04 LTS and suddenly I started to see that error in Apache logs. I confirm that after changing the policy as described here the problem was solved.

Comment: This is the minimal correct answer - sNICkerssss's answer is technically correct however only one step is needed for command-line usage of `convert` to PDF.

Comment: This 'problem' is quick&dirty 'fix' to Ghostscript functionality, in long term we should find replacement for Ghostscript (and likely ImageMagick).

Comment: Don't do this. This restriction has been introduced as a security measure because of possible remote code execution (see https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/imagemagick/8:6.7.7.10-6ubuntu3.13). So the correct answer is: You should use another program for this task.

Comment: Make sure to update ghostscript https://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/332928/

Answer (score 71):

> **Note: this solution and any other "edit the policy.xml" solution disables safety measures against arbitrary code execution vulnerabilities in ImageMagick. If you need to process input that you do not control 100%, you should use a different program (not ImageMagick).**

If you're still here, you are trying to edit images that you have complete control over, know are safe, and cannot be edited by users.

There is an `/etc/ImageMagick/policy.xml` file that is installed by yum.  It disallows almost everything (for security and to protect your system from getting overloaded with ImageMagick calls).

If you're getting a `ReadImage` error as above, you can change the line to:

```
<policy domain="coder" rights="read" pattern="LABEL" />
```

which should fix the issue.

The file has a bunch of documentation in it, so you should read that. For example, if you need more permissions, you can combine them like:

```
<policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="LABEL" />
```

...which is preferable to removing all permissions checks (i.e., deleting or commenting out the line).

Comment: Don't do this. This restriction has been introduced as a security measure because of possible remote code execution (see https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/imagemagick/8:6.7.7.10-6ubuntu3.13). So the correct answer is: You should use another program for this task.

Comment: Make sure to update ghostscript https://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/332928/

Comment: @Marian Using another program is not helpful - the OP asked specifically about ImageMagick.  The response should be "You should know what you are doing, do it at your own risk, make sure you system is secure, here is why you shouldn't, and here is how to do it".

Comment: The OP (and people getting here by web search, including me) have been using ImageMagick until now; so of course, their first try in solving this issue is finding a solution using ImageMagick, because that requires the least amount of changes. That doesn't mean they unconditionally want to use ImageMagick.

Comment: I find this dismissive approach to security very inappropriate for a Q&A site seen by thousands (this page has been viewed 100k times and is the top search result for this problem) — and let's be clear here, there was a large and vocal attempt to stress the importance of this vulnerability, including a dedicated site set up to publicise it (https://imagetragick.com/) — Marian's suggestion that alternatives should be sought rather than security bypassed is valid. I chose to use GIMP instead. `poppler` is an alternative to GhostScript (which `convert` relies on to rasterize PDF pages to images)

Comment: Isn't there a command line option to disable the security policy temporarily? Then we could use it for specific PDF files that we trust.

Answer (score 30):

If someone need to do it with one command after install, run this !

```
sed -i 's/<policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PDF" \/>/<policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PDF" \/>/g' /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml
```

Comment: Shorter: `sed -i 's/\(<policy domain="coder" rights=\)"none" \(pattern="PDF" \/>\)/\1"read|write"\2/g' /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml`

Comment: More concise. And sudo is required to edit a file inside /etc

`sudo sed -i '/PDF/s/none/read|write/' /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml`

Comment: make sure to update ghostscript https://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/332928/

Answer (score 26):

Just delete `/etc/ImageMagick/policy.xml` file. E.g.

```
rm /etc/<ImageMagick_PATH>/policy.xml
```

For ImageMagick 6, it's:

```
sudo rm /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml
```

Comment: simple yet perfect. i did this as the test is failing on travis

Comment: This is the only solution that worked from tons of posts. I renamed it to `policy-disabled.xml`. I think I will restore it until I'm certain that the security issues are addressed

Comment: And after restart your kernel in the case of jupyter notebook

Answer (score 25):

The answer with highest votes (I have not enough reputation to add comment there) suggests to comment out the MVG line, but have in mind this:

> CVE-2016-3714
>
> ImageMagick supports ".svg/.mvg" files which means that attackers can
>   craft code in a scripting language, e.g. MSL (Magick Scripting
>   Language) and MVG (Magick Vector Graphics), upload it to a server
>   disguised as an image file and force the software to run malicious
>   commands on the server side as described above. For example adding the
>   following commands in a file and uploading it to a webserver that uses
>   a vulnerable ImageMagick version will result in running the command
>   "ls -la" on the server.
>
> exploit.jpg:
>
> push graphic-context viewbox 0 0 640 480 fill
>   'url(https://website.com/image.png"|ls "-la)' pop graphic-context

And

> Any version below 7.0.1-2 or 6.9.4-0 is potentially vulnerable and
>   affected parties should as soon as possible upgrade to the latest
>   ImageMagick version.

[Source](https://www.enisa.europa.eu/publications/info-notes/what2019s-behind-imagemagick-vulnerability)

Comment: I didn't comment out MVG and PDF -> JPG conversion still works. Thank you.

Comment: 6.7.7-10 *looks* like the newest version, released 9/28/2018). What am I missing? ```$convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2018-09-28 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org```

Comment: there is newer version http://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php Probably your Linux distribution uses older one. Ubuntu 16.04 currently uses 6.8.9-9

Comment: Nice, so the proper solution for Ubuntu team would be to update imagemagick to newer version, not to break the existing one.

Comment: No.  Ubuntu is a feature-freeze distribution and will not ship upstream newer releases.

Comment: make sure to update ghostscript https://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/332928/

Comment: RHEL is also feature-freeze, but bear in mind they're explicitly _not_ "security-freeze"; i.e. security vulnerabilities are backported from big-numbered versions. That means the OP is probably safe. Let's check! https://access.redhat.com/security/vulnerabilities/ImageTragick - Indeed. https://access.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2016:0726 So go ahead and change your policy.xml file.

Comment: Addendum: on RHEL6, check programmatically with `r=$(rpm -q ImageMagick --qf '%{release}') && [[ ${r%.*} -gt 4 ]]`

Answer (score 19):

After a recent update on my Ubuntu 16.04 system I have also started getting this error when trying to run convert on .ps files to convert them into pdfs.

This fix worked for me:

In a terminal run:

```
sudo gedit /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml
```

This should open the policy.xml file in the gedit text editor. If it doesn't, your image magick might be installed in a different place. 
Then change

```
rights="none"
```

to

```
rights="read | write"
```

for PDF, EPS and PS lines near the bottom of the file. Save and exit, and image magick should then work again.

Comment: make sure to update ghostscript https://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/332928/

Comment: This helped on Ubuntu 18.04 ImageMagick 6.9.7-4. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I had this error when trying to convert a pdf to jpg and solved it using this method:
sudo vi /etc/ImageMagick*/policy.xml

change:

policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PDF"

to:

policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PDF"

Source: http://realtechtalk.com/ImageMagick_Convert_PDF_Not_Authorized-2217-articles

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need to handle raster files and PDF/PS/EPS through the same tool, don't loosen ImageMagick's security.

Instead, keep your defense in depth for your web applications intact, check that your Ghostscript has been patched for all known `-dSAFER` vulnerabilities and then invoke it directly.

```sh
gs -dSAFER -r300 -sDEVICE=png16m -o document-%03d.png document.pdf
```

- `-dSAFER` opts you out of the legacy-compatibility "run Postscript will full permission to interact with the outside world as a turing-complete programming language" mode.
- `-r300` sets the desired DPI to 300 (the default is 72)
- `-sDEVICE` specifies the output format (See the [Devices section](https://ghostscript.com/doc/9.21/Devices.htm#PNG) of the manual for other choices.)
- `-o` is a shorthand for `-dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sOutputFile=`
- [This section](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm#One_page_per_file) of the Ghostscript manual gives some example formats for for multi-file filename output but, for the actual syntax definition, it points you at the documentation for the C [printf(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) function.

If you're rendering EPS files, add `-dEPSCrop` so it won't pad your output to page size and use `-sDEVICE=pngalpha` to get transparent backgrounds.

Comment: Thanks for a safer solution. Not sure I'll ever be able to remember the GhostScript command line options, though! :)

Comment: @CrisLuengo I won't either. That's why I posted it to as many Google results as I could find where it was a good answer to the question posed. :P

Comment: I found good results using `-r600 -dDownScaleFactor=4` to create a file with a 150 dpi but better anti-aliasing.

Answer (score 3):

After reading several suggestions here and combining the ideas, for me following changes in /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml were necessary:

```
<policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PDF" />
```

... rights="none" did not help. ...pattern="LABEL" was not neccessary.
Although I do not work with big png files (only ~1 Mb) some changes in memory limits were also necessary:

```
<policy domain="resource" name="memory" value="2GiB"/>
```

(instead of 256Mib), and

```
<policy domain="resource" name="area" value="2GB"/>
```

(instead of 128 MB)

Answer (score 1):

I also had the error `error/constitute.c/ReadImage/453`  when trying to convert an eps to a gif with image magick. I tried the solution proposed by sNICkerssss but still had errors (though different from the first one)e `error/constitute.c/ReadImage/412`
What solved the problem was to put `read` to other entries

```
 <policy domain="coder" rights="read" pattern="PS" />
 <policy domain="coder" rights="read" pattern="EPS" />
 <policy domain="coder" rights="read" pattern="PDF" />
 <policy domain="coder" rights="read" pattern="XPS" />
 <policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="LABEL" />
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21070171)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I edited my answer in the meantime. Anyway I really felt it should have been a comment on sNICkerssss answer, but since I cannot add it is the best way I figured out

Comment: @Sirence it is an answer, thought poor because it copies from other answers.

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo my comment was from before the edit. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52700739/revisions