# Carrierwave pdf upload failed to manipulate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, rmagick

I am using CarrierWave for file uploads in my application. All of sudden since 6th October 2018, pdf files are not able to upload, and app raises this error:

```
Failed to manipulate with MiniMagick, maybe it is not an image? Original Error: 
`identify /tmp/mini_magick20181010-10534-s5jchg.pdf` failed with error: 
identify: not authorized `/tmp/mini_magick20181010-10534-s5jchg.pdf' @ 
error/constitute.c/ReadImage/412.
```

There are lot of question on same but none of the answers have solved this issue. I have also tried with Rmagick but no luck.

Below is my uploader set up

```
class AttachmentUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  #storage :file
  storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  def default_url
    "no-photo.png"
  end


  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:

  version :thumb do
    # crop to exactly 80px x 80px
    process :resize_to_fill => [80, 80]
  end

  version :web do
    # scale to be no larger than 800px x 500px
    process :resize_to_limit => [800, 500]
  end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  # def extension_white_list
  #   %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  # end

  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
  # def filename
  #   "something.jpg" if original_filename
  # end

end
```

Let me know your thoughts.

Thank you

Comment: not working for pdf because your uploader's manipulators are specifically designed for images and they can't work on pdf?

Comment: add `, :if => :image?` after `version :thumb` and `version :web` ?

Comment: Ya, agree I have made those changes but I'm wondering how that was working before.

Comment: maybe the version updated and they used to handle something like this before? not sure

Comment: Hopefully you're using git version control and can see what may have changed in your code?  Have you found a solution?  You may not need `CarrierWave::MiniMagick` did you try to comment it out?

Comment: I have removed MiniMagic and manipulator and its working me. But I just wanted to know how it stopped suddenly.

Answer (score 1):

This was caused by a security update in ImageMagick that was released in Oct 2018 (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/imagemagick/8:6.7.7.10-6ubuntu3.13).

There's a pretty simple fix. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52661288/935514.

Note: you only need to change the `<policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PDF" />` line and you only need to restart the web workers, not the entire server.