# convert: not authorized `tieps' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/412

Tags: imagemagick-convert, eps

I want to create a png by use convert from ImageMagick. After issuing the command:
`convert tes.eps tes.png` 
i got the following error:

```
convert: not authorized `tieps' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/412.
```

I have already visited the previous stack overflow question here:[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42928765/convertnot-authorized-aaaa-error-constitute-c-readimage-453) and changed line

```
<policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="EPS" />
```

to

```
<policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="EPS" />
```

it doesn't work. I can create a eps by `convert timg.png ti1.eps`. However it still have the same error for `convert tes.eps tes.png` .

Comment: Do you have Ghostscript installed as a delegate to ImageMagick? ImageMagick uses Ghostscript to process EPS, PS and PDF. Did you uncomment your modified policy for EPS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert:not authorized \`aaaa\` @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/453](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42928765/convertnot-authorized-aaaa-error-constitute-c-readimage-453)

Answer (score 0):

You wrote that you changed the original line to an other but if however you did comment the old line and wrote the new line remember to use comment style

```
<!-- the_commented_command   -->
```

Using # character for starting a comment won't work in the policy file