# How do I export a R/exams question with a tikzpicture to moodle?

Tags: r-exams

I'm using the Template [logic: Interpretation of Logic Gates (Using TikZ)](http://www.r-exams.org/templates/logic/) but I get the following error when I tried to export do moodle:

```
exams2moodle('logic.Rnw',name='TEST')

Erro:  chunk 2 
Error in magick_image_readpath(path, density, depth, strip, defines) : 
  rsession: not authorized `/tmp/RtmptUvxDm/file2d826c1a0925/tex2image/A.pdf' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/412
```

Comment: I don't think that this is specific to Moodle, you should get the same for `exams2html()`. I'm not sure though what the solution is, seems to be about the permissions in your temporary directory.

Comment: Rather than permissions regarding the directory, it appears that this is about ImageMagick policies being used. Please check whether this resolves your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42928765/convertnot-authorized-aaaa-error-constitute-c-readimage-453

Comment: Did you have a look at the other post I linked above? Did fixing the ImageMagick policies resolve your problem? If so, I guess this would be interesting for other R/exams users as well and we should turn it into a proper accepted answer here on StackOverflow.