# Get images from pdf using php

Tags: php, image, pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I extract images from a PDF file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430707/how-can-i-extract-images-from-a-pdf-file)
>   [Read pdf files with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004478/read-pdf-files-with-php)

Does anyone know how to get images from PDF files using php?

And I also need to get where those images are situated on the page of the PDF-file... Something like x and y coordinates of one of the corners and the size of an image.

Maybe it's possible to parse PDF pages to layers or something like that...

Thanks to everyone who would try to help!