# extract raster and vector images from pdf with a bash script

Tags: bash, pdf, vector-graphics

I needed a bash script which extracts all the raster and vector images from the pdf and convert them to jpg format.

I checked many posts on the web and I got most of the ideas from these
[How can I extract images from a PDF file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430707/how-can-i-extract-images-from-a-pdf-file)
[Count the number of the raster images in the pdf](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=21963)
[How to extract a vector figure from pdf?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429066/how-to-extract-a-vector-figure-from-pdf)

It works and I share it because I didn't find a solution on the web like this.

But there are 2 small issues that I couldn't fix so far.

1. If there is a page with texts then `pdf2svg` will determine the texts as vector images and will generate an extra image with the texts.
   **Is there any way to distinguish the text from the real vector images?**
2. If there are multiple vector images on one page then `pdf2svg` will generate one SVG image which contains all the vector images (same like a page contains text). **Is it possible to extract them into separated images?**

the bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

TMP_DIR=$1
SOURCE_PDF=$2
MAX_WIDTH=1920
MAX_HEIGHT=1080

echo "source: $SOURCE_PDF"


function burst
{
    local source=$1

    # explodes the pages to pdf files (it is necessary for the vector images export)
    `/usr/bin/pdftk $source burst`

    # removes the source pdf (we do not need it any more)
    rm $source

    # and the txt files which were generated by the pdftk
    rm *.txt
}


# finds the pages as pdf files and call check_for_images function
function process_pages {
    local tmp_dir=$1
    local pnum=1

    for f in `find . -type f -name "*.pdf"`
    do
        echo "processing page $f"
        check_for_images $f $pnum
        let "pnum++"
    done
}



function check_for_images {
    local pdf_page=$1
    local pnum=$2

    # checks whether the page contains a raster image
    list_raster_images=`/usr/bin/pdfimages -list $pdf_page | grep -E "(jpeg|png|gif)"`
    is_raster_images=${#list_raster_images}

    if (( $is_raster_images > 0 )); then
        # it contains raster image(s), extract them
        extract_raster_images $pdf_page $pnum
    else
        # it does not contain raster image(s), try to extract vector images
        extract_vector_images $pdf_page $pnum
    fi;

    rm $pdf_page
}


function extract_raster_images {
    local pdf_page=$1
    local pnum=$2

    pdf_file="${pdf_page%.*}"

    echo "extract all raster image(s) from this page";
    `/usr/bin/pdfimages -all $pdf_page ./`

    # we need to use a very same file name convention so this part renames them
    # who knows it might be useful later
    for f in `find . -regextype sed -regex ".*/-[0-9]\{3\}\.jpg"`
    do
        path=$(dirname $f)
        img_file=$(basename $f)
        img_ext="${img_file##*.}"
        img_num="${img_file%.*}"
        mv $f $path/$pdf_file$img_num.$img_ext
    done
}



function extract_vector_images {
    local pdf_page=$1
    local pnum=$2

    pdf_file="${pdf_page%.*}"

    echo "extract vector image from the page as SVG"
    `/usr/bin/pdf2svg $pdf_page $pdf_page.svg`

    # just to be sure it is not a raster image
    is_raster_image=`grep -c -i "data:image" $pdf_page.svg`
    if (( $is_raster_images == 0 )); then
        # convert SVG to PNG (it doesn't know JPG format) with fixed sizes, but keep the aspect ratio
        `/usr/bin/rsvg-convert -a -w $MAX_WIDTH -h $MAX_HEIGHT -f png -o $pdf_page.png $pdf_page.svg`
        # convert PNG to JPG
        `convert $pdf_page.png -background white -flatten -alpha off $pdf_file-000.jpg`
    fi;

    `rm *.svg`
    `rm *.png`
}


cd $TMP_DIR
burst $SOURCE_PDF
process_pages $TMP_DIR
```

executing it from php

```
$tmpName = basename($file['tmp_name']);
$tmpDir  = '/path-of-tmp-dir' . $tmpName . '_extraction';

mkdir($tmpDir);

$command = "extract_pdf_images.sh $tmpDir ".$file['tmp_name'];

exec($command);
```

requirements

```
apt-get install pdftk pdfimages pdf2svg librsvg2-bin imagick
```

Comment: @amphetamachine I wrote and used this script >7 years ago. I don't remember why did I do that. I have removed the backticks around the rm-s.

Comment: Glad to see you've been continuing to learn shell in the intervening 7 years. :-)